# Request timed out. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running (somewhat complex) query on the browser UI, and after a very long time (hours) getting "Request timed out. Please try again."
When I remove some "join" or "where" conditions it runs on reasonable time.
I believe something is wrong with the query, but i cannot identify whats the problematic bit. Is there any available tool that can show the "query execution plan" and hint what might cause the issue?

My query contains some window functions within a sub-query and where conditions relates to the window function fields in an outer where clause. is there known issue with such queries?

for the BQ guys, my job id is: job_7b2zNSZQMFu1WWqRJnqBWs2q2wA

Thanks